# How to remove epoxy on clothes

Tags: cleaning

How to remove epoxy on clothes?
More precisely in my case, how to remove the hardener of epoxy, which consists to components: hardener and resin?

Comment: Lestoil, PineSol or other organic-solvent cleaner should get out the unset hardener. Once set, epoxy is hard to remove; you might try methylene chloride-based paint removers [toxic!]. Some hardeners are organic peroxides, which may bleach spots on the clothing.

Comment: Epoxy materials are hard to destroy. I remember that only thing that was forbidden to use on them (according to a guy who did this flooring) is to spill alcohol on it. Maybe you can try this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardener is water soluble. Soap and water will remove it. Probably scrape it first if there's a lot.

Comment: are you sure about this? I worked with epoxy materials (I used them for flooring) and they are well known as nearly indestructible; people use them in industry facilities etc. Have you tried this advice?

Comment: it has worked for me on unmixed hardener. there may well be chemicals that will be more effective though. i may have answered too soon.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will try and update the result to you.

Comment: This site (from a manufacturer) agrees. http://www.westsystem.com/ss/clean-up-removing
It appears though that there are a range of different chemicals used as hardeners, which may require different solvents (I'm including water as a solvent here).
Can we have the exact product name?